# Return a file from ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to make a web application with ASP.NET. The main task is that the user fills a form and the application creates some XML files, compresses them into a zip file, and returns a URL to the user so he/she could download that file.

But I don't know where I should start.

I've created the application as a C# console application, but don't know how to create it as a web application - what is the approach?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a web application with ASP.NET, you can use a framework such as [ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/introduction-to-aspnet-core?view=aspnetcore-6.0) or [ASP.NET MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/). These frameworks help you with tasks such as handling user requests, managing sessions, and serving content to the user.

[image]

After creating ASP.NET web application project, your IDE will generate some default files and folders you can use as a starting point.

- Create a web form that will allow users to input the necessary information for generating the XML files. You can use HTML and Razor syntax to define the form and any associated views.
- Create a controller action that will handle form submissions and generate the XML files. This action will take the form input as parameters, process the data, and create the XML files. You can use the System.Xml namespace to work with XML files in C#.
- Use a library like System.IO.Compression.ZipFile to compress the generated XML files into a zip file.

Finally, return a URL to the user that points to the compressed file. You can use ASP.NET's built-in response methods to serve the file to the user for download.